# jquery pass variable to next pages to display images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, variables

I have two HTML which is (simply name is as one.html & two.html)
for the two.html, i have a query string, when the url show two.html?var=1 it will show images that i set at the jquery.
[two.html sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Leelala/KQ8F7/) (not sure why not working at jsfiddle, when the code in local it working fine.)

HTML

```
 <div class="itemabc"><img src="http://s7.postimg.org/7zbcr6ytz/photo1.jpg id="item1" /></div>
```

Jquery

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
    var target = getParameterByName('var');
    if (target == 1) {
      $("#item1").attr("src","http://s7.postimg.org/7zbcr6ytz/photo1.jpg");
    }
    else if (target == 2){
        $("#item1").attr("src","http://s22.postimg.org/v6gqap331/photo2.jpg");
    }

    else if (target == 3){
        $("#item1").attr("src","http://s22.postimg.org/anqfjdejh/photo3.jpg");
    }

    else if (target == 4){
        $("#item1").attr("src","http://s22.postimg.org/75efmzdnh/photo4.jpg");
    }


    else if (target == 5){
        $("#item1").attr("src","http://s22.postimg.org/9pa2h317h/photo5.jpg");
    }

    else {
        $("#item1").attr("src","http://s22.postimg.org/mfeau695p/photo6.jpg");
    }

  });
  function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }
```

And then, now i don't know how to post the variable to two.html,
reason why i doing this, because i'll have few item to be select at one.html, then after send, two.html will display what i select previously.

Comment: Have you thought about using a cookie and writing/reading data from the cookie? See something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Comment: @Cymen Using a cookie? This question is most commonly solved with GET variables!

Comment: @ArunPJohny They are not on the same folder

Comment: @Itay missed that.. then storing them in an array will be a better choice

Comment: maybe your url number is actually a string?  Try `parseInt()` on it.  Also, I'm personally fond of local storage.

Comment: why not use ajax load one.html and two.html in single page programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get parameter from url in javascript

please review this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)